# Puzzled about Boost Bufferstream implementation

Tags: c++, boost

I often use the **[Boost Interprocess library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)**, which provides an I/O stream class, `bufferstream`, which is basically similar to `std::stringstream`, except it operates over an arbitrary user-provided memory buffer.

I've used this stream class extensively, and I've also used it's source code to learn a lot about implementing/extending C++ I/O streams in general.

However, one piece of implementation code has struck me as very weird, and I'd like to see if anyone knows exactly why the Boost designer implemented it this way.

Specifically, it's a function in the streambuffer class `boost::interprocess::basic_bufferbuf`.  This class inherits from `std::basic_streambuf`, and overrides all the virtual protected methods to provide specific behavior.

The [**source code**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/interprocess/streams/bufferstream.hpp) can be browsed online here.

Specifically, the function `basic_bufferbuf::seekpos()` is implemented as follows:

```
   virtual pos_type seekpos(pos_type pos, std::ios_base::openmode mode
                                 = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out)
   {  return seekoff(pos - pos_type(off_type(0)), std::ios_base::beg, mode);  }
```

Generally, stream buffer implementations which override `std::basic_streambuf::seekpos()` just call `std::basic_streambuf::seekoff` with the starting position set to `std::ios_base::beg`, so that's normal.

But why does the implementor write `pos - pos_type(off_type(0))` here?  Why subtract zero from the starting position?  What possible use is that?

I suspect it must have something to do with unusual `off_type` or `pos_type` types, but I can't imagine what.  Generally, `pos_type` and `off_type` are just signed integral types.

So why subtract zero here?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132458/why-does-the-standard-have-both-seekpos-and-seekoff

Comment: So I think it's to convert `pos` to an `off_type` since `seekoff` needs an `off_type`.

Comment: But then why not just say `seekoff(offtype(pos), std::ios_base::beg, mode);`  Why subtract zero?