# Why does the standard have both seekpos() and seekoff()?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The title pretty much says it all.

I am implementing my own streambuf class, and I am wondering what the Committee was thinking when they decided to include both `std::streambuf::seekpos()` and `std::streambuf::seekoff()` (and similarly for the related `pubseekpos()` and `pubseekoff()`).

It seems to me that `seekpos(x)` should have the same effect as `seekoff(x, std::ios::beg)` in every circumstance I can imagine. But perhaps my imagination is not good enough. So, why would you want to have both when `seekpos` is completely subsumed by `seekoff`? Or at least, why would you not make the default implementation of the former simply invoke the latter?

If the answer is "because that is what the STL did" or similar, then assume I am asking about the rationale for the STL or similar.

(I realize that the first argument of `seekpos` is a `streampos` while the first argument of `seekoff` is a `streamoff`. But note that 27.4.3.2 [lib.fpos.operations] requires that stream positions be convertible to stream offsets and back, so I do not think this is the answer.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The two functions use different parameters:

- [`seekpos()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/seekpos/) positions you in a stream, using an absolute [`streampos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/streampos/) position
- [`seekoff()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/seekoff/) positions you in a stream, using a relative [`streamoff`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/streamoff/) offset compared to a given position (begin, current, or end)

You are perfectly right:  they can be converted in both direction.  But there is a subtle semantic difference:

- `streampos` is intuitively related to a fixed position whereas `streamoff` is somehow related to motion in a file.
- substracting one `streampos` from another `streampos` makes a `streamoff`.
- adding a `streampos` to a `streamoff` makes a new `streampos`.
- other combinations are valid, thanks to the easy conversion, but require more care.
- wide streams use `wstreampos` for the position (because obviously a position within a `wchar_t` has a different meaning as a position in a `char` stream).
- but wide streams use `streamoff` for motion, as it is a relative movement compared to a position.

If you use template programming, these semantic differences are more explicit with the traits: `S::pos_type` and `S::off_type`.

## Real origin

Regardless of these semantic subtilities, the real origin of this difference is historical, and related to the **C standard library**, as explained by Mr. Plauger in [this article](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/CUJ/1994/9406/plauger/plauger.htm):

- `streamoff` was designed with [`fseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fseek.html) and `ftell()` of the C standard library in mind, which use a `long` for positioning.
- `streampos` was meant for [`fgetpos()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgetpos.html) and `fsetpos()` which use an `fpos_t` argument.

I could verify that this was already the case in C89 standard.  As neither of these functions were mentionned in the original K&R, maybe a UNIX historian could tell more about an even more distant path.

[This paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2926.pdf) explains the more recent thoughts of the standard committee.  It appears that the historic difference is questioned and that it is no longer clear whether it is still really needed.

Comment: Nice answer; +1 and accepted. The key, I think, is that C does not require `fpos_t` (the argument to `fsetpos`) to be convertible to `long` or `off_t` (the argument to `fseek` or `fseeko`). As soon as you allow that conversion, the setpos/seekpos interfaces become redundant.

Comment: @Christophe, You mention `streamoff` twice in the bulleted list - I think you meant `streampos` the second time.  I tried to edit your answer to fix this, but it wouldn't let me (apparently there is a 6-char minimum for edits)

Comment: @Siler you are completely right !  Thanks for your feedback: I've corrected it

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering what the Committee was thinking when they decided to include both std::streambuf::seekpos() and std::streambuf::seekoff() (and similarly for the related pubseekpos() and pubseekoff()).

`streampos` represents an absolute position from the beginning of the stream.  Thus, `seekpos()` seeks to a specific position.

`streamoff` represents an offset from a given position.  Thus, `seekoff()` can seek relative to any given position.  That is why it has a `dir` parameter to specify how the offset is to be interpreted - an offset from the beginning/end of the stream, or an offset relative to the stream's current position.

Different semantics, so different functions provided.

> It seems to me that seekpos(x) should have the same effect as seekoff(x, std::ios::beg) in every circumstance I can imagine.

That is logically what it does, yes.  Though the actual implementation could be optimized, such as by taking the current position into account to minimize the amount of physical seeking involved, especially for file streams.  It is not always efficient to make the OS go all the way back to the beginning of the file just to move forward again.

> So, why would you want to have both when seekpos is completely subsumed by seekoff?

Because sometimes it makes sense to seek to a specific position directly, and sometimes it makes sense to seek to a relative offset.  It depends on the circumstance.  Both cases have their uses.

> So, why would you want to have both when seekpos is completely subsumed by seekoff?

Convenience.  Depends on the design of the calling code, whether it keeps track of absolute positions or relative offsets.

> Or at least, why would you not make the default implementation of the former simply invoke the latter?

It could be.  It is implementation-defined.

> But note that 27.4.3.2 [lib.fpos.operations] requires that stream positions be convertible to stream offsets and back, so I do not think this is the answer.)

*Convertible* being the key word here.  Just because they can be *converted* to each other does not mean they are *semantically equal* to each other.

Comment: So you agree that any time you write `seekpos(x)` you could instead write `seekoff(x,std::ios::beg)` (and similarly for `pubseekpos` and `pubseekoff`) and get exactly the same behavior, with literally no conceivable real-life exception whatsoever? By the way,  you are wrong that the default behavior of `seekpos` "is implementation-defined". The default (i.e. base) `std::streambuf::seekpos` returns `pos_type(off_type(-1))`, by definition, according to paragraph 27.5.2.4.2 (6) of the standard.

Comment: Just because you *can* doesn't always mean you *should*. And like I said, a stream's `seekpos()` and `seekoff()` implementations could be optimized separately. For instance, a file stream's `seekpos()` might grab the current position, calculate a `streamoff` value to the new position, and then `seekoff(theoffset, std::ios::cur)` to reach `x`. That is usually a more efficient seek on the filesystem/hardware than using `seekoff(x, std::ios::beg)`.  For a memory stream, `seekpos()` can just jump to the new position directly.

Comment: Since you agree they are 100% behaviorally equivalent under all circumstances, any optimization you can imagine for `seekpos` would apply equally well to `seekoff(...,std::ios::beg)`. So that is a non-argument. (Never mind that if you care about making C++ streams more efficient, this is a ludicrous place to start...)